# Cannot access 'cpa' before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm getting the error above from this route:

```
router.put('/edit/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const cpa = await CPASchema.findById(req.params.id).then(() => {
    res.render('edit', { cpa:cpa });
    console.log("EDIT QUESTION")
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  })
})
```

Any idea where the problem could be? Thank you.

Comment: When using `await` you don't need the `then`

Comment: @outlaw thank you, I just realized that too.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
router.put('/edit/:id', async (req, res)=> {
    const cpa = await CPASchema.findById(req.params.id)
    res.render('edit', {cpa:cpa});
      
    console.log("EDIT QUESTION")
})
```